# Composing non-flat schema in BigQuery with C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-bigquery

I've been using the `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2` nuget package and don't seem to be able to find any concrete examples of creating a non-trivial (by this, I mean non-flat) schema for table creation / row insertion.

Let's take this object as an example:

```
public class DataEntry
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The `Items` dictionary may be null/empty or contain many entries.

From reading the docs, I'd expect `.Items` to be mapped as an `ARRAY` of `STRUCT<string, string>`, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually map this kind of object in code.

Can anyone point me to an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more reading, it's become clear that whilst you can specify an `ARRAY` in your schema when adding a field of type `BigQueryDbType.DateTime` to a `TableSchemaBuilder`, it cannot be combined with a `STRUCT` to map a dictionary.  The reason for this is, with hindsight, fairly obvious - a `STRUCT` is essentially like a `System.Object` in that it's properties (dictionary keys) need to be known ahead of time.

In short, this will never work for my scenario since the dictionary key/value pairs are dynamic and won't be known beforehand.

After digging into the supported query-time functions, I came across the `JSON_EXTRACT` function which provides a way out. By flattening the dictionary into json and storing it with a basetype of `BigQueryDbType.String`, I have a way to persist the dynamic data and query it on the other end.

Armed with this information, the code to build a schema for the object above, would look something like this:

```
// Build our object
var builder = new TableSchemaBuilder();
builder.Add("Id", BigQueryDbType.String, BigQueryFieldMode.Required);
builder.Add("Name", BigQueryDbType.String, BigQueryFieldMode.Required);
builder.Add("Inserted", BigQueryDbType.DateTime, BigQueryFieldMode.Required);
// ...
// ... Rest of fields
// ...
builder.Add("Items", BigQueryDbType.String, BigQueryFieldMode.Nullable);

// Build our schema
var schema = builder.Build();
```

Assuming an `Items` value of `{"KeyOne":"ItemOne", "KeyTwo":"ItemTwo"}`, the query to tease out the first value in the dictionary would look something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(Items, "$.KeyOne") AS KeyOne FROM `mytable` LIMIT 1000
```

Hopefully this will save someone else some time :)